# Sharepoint administration?

Tags: sharepoint, monitoring, reporting

I am new to MOSS/SharePoint administration. Any pointers on any utilities which can help me in monitoring/reporting MOSS?

Also, is it possible to generate site specific reports for storage space used for each site?

Answer (score 3):

For monitoring disk used: [SharePoint Space Monitor](http://www.thesug.org/blogs/lsuslinky/SSM/Pages/default.aspx)

[On Reporting](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/44cf0578-2137-4816-8c8e-b163d9567c58/).

For general administration of sharepoint, theres is a wealth of information available online on Microsoft's site, also many books have been published on the topic. Check Google.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to take a look at the SharePoint administration toolkit. It includes the SharePoint Diagnostics Tool which gives you a unified view of your SharePoint farm.

[SharePoint Administration Toolkit Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=263CD480-F6EB-4FA3-9F2E-2D47618505F2&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

If your new to SharePoint I'd suggest checking out either of the following admin tools.

http://www.quest.com/sharepoint/administration.aspx

http://www.axceler.com/products/controlpoint.html

Both tools offer the features your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're the scripting, command-line type(even otherwise), I would recommend learning up on two items:

- Stsadm - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261956.aspx
- Powershell - http://masteringsharepoint.com/blogs/bobmixon/archive/2008/08/15/powershell-and-sharepoint.aspx

Storage stats could be calculated using something like [this](http://blogs.flexnetconsult.co.uk/colinbyrne/2006/12/17/MOSSPersonalSitesStillTopLevel.aspx):